# How to copy/paste tab characters via the Clipboard into terminal session on gnome / ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, clipboard

How do i copy text that includes tab characters  from a text editor, let's say gedit into a terminal session on ubuntu/gnome?  I am on ubuntu 12.0.4 using gnome classic.

**UPDATE** This same issue happens in CentOs - basically seems to apply to any gnome.

Comment: For OSX: http://superuser.com/questions/687240/how-to-paste-a-tab-into-os-x-terminal-from-clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any solution to this.

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to paste into the terminal prompt, or into a text file opened in the terminal? If the former, could you explain why you would need that?

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned on the [OS X version of this question](https://superuser.com/a/1577258/54690), pasting tabs works fine.  But **copying** them in the first place is tricky on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the text you want to copy, and then middle click on the terminal. On most *nix systems, selecting copies and middle click pastes.

Alternatively, you can select => right click=>copy => terminal => right click=> paste

Or, simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Have a look [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/xclipboard.html) for a short explanation of the Linux/Unix clipboard and the X buffer.

Comment: I neglected to mention the problem focuses on tab characters getting lost.

Comment: @javadba selecting and middle clicking should copy tabs across correctly. In fact all of them should.

Comment: Tabs definitely get lost with control c: pls test yourself - does "middle click" keep the tabs? i have 2 button mouse only

Comment: @javadba if you have a two button mouse, you can emulate the middle click by clicking both buttons at the same time. I did try it and both Ctrl+V and Middle click copy the tabs correctly on my system. Are you sure you have tabs there? You can check with `od -c file.txt`.

Comment: (a) clicking both left and right is not working   (b) I usually do not have an external mouse anyways and no middle click on trackpad. So in the end I still do not have a solution. I came back here to my own question via googling over a year later.

Comment: @terdon: No, middle-click doesn't work either. Tabs disappear from the pasted text. At least with gnome-terminal.

Comment: @mivk I don't understand this. It works fine for me and always has, across at least 5 different Linux distributions. Are you trying to paste the text directly onto the command line? If so, why would you need that? That's the only case where I see this happening and I can't imagine a use case for it. It works as expected if you first run `cat > file` and then paste, for instance. Feel free to come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and ping me and I'll see if we can find a workaround.

Comment: Five years later it's a tad challenging to remember the use case: but at least *one* of them was pasting into `REPL` : could be `ipython` or `scala` prompt or `jruby` or ..

Comment: Fair enough, someone commented on my answer today which is why I brought it up again, and I just realized you were probably trying to paste directly into some sort of prompt, which makes my answer completely irrelevant. My belated apology, I thought you were pasting into the terminal (something like `cat > file` as I mentioned above). For what it's worth, in `ipython` you can do it with `cpaste`.

Comment: @terdon: yes, I was pasting directly into the command-line, to test a regex before using it on a file. Specifically into `echo "Trying-to-paste-in-here" | perl -nle ...` etc. In such a case, tabs get removed, and this is how I landed on this question. Not a big deal, but it was disconcerting and I thought there was something wrong with my terminal.