# How to paste a tab into OS X Terminal from clipboard?

Tags: macos, terminal, tabs, clipboard

Tabs are getting removed from text that I paste into the Terminal. Any suggestions?

An example of my use case is to paste sections of TSV files into a remote ssh session terminal, bypassing the tedious multi-hop scp process.

This is not about using other editors/tools (e.g. emacs/vi)  and I am already aware of how to enter a  single tab char via CTL-Tab.  These do not meet the need.

Comment: I think we'll need more info than that about what you're doing. When I ssh into another computer, run `cat >data.tsv`, and then paste in tab-delimited data (followed by Control-D to terminate the file), it works as expected. You must be doing something that's different from this in some important way, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: For Ubuntu: http://superuser.com/questions/607410/how-to-copy-paste-tab-characters-via-the-clipboard-into-terminal-session-on-gnom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, because you have to consider not only the pasting operation, but also the original copying step.

Indeed in OS X it seems to be impossible to paste a tab character in the Terminal app.  On the other hand, pasting a tab into some other app (such as TextEdit) works fine.

On Linux, it's kinda the opposite.  Pasting tabs works fine; but **copying** them in the first place is a problem.  It depends on where you're trying to copy them from.  If you simply dump the contents of a file onto your terminal (with `cat` for example), any tab characters get expanded: replaced with some number of spaces.  If you then tried to select the text and copy from the terminal output, it would be too late.  Note that it's not the `cat` program itself that does the expansion, it's the lower-level device driver or terminal emulator.

It's instructive to consider OS X again.  On OS X, the `stty` command has an option to control whether tabs should be expanded on output or not.  If you run `stty oxtabs` and then try to dump some text to Terminal, you would see that the tabs get expanded, as they unconditionally do on Linux, and if you try to copy/paste that output the tabs are replaced.

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to insert a tab, you can press control-v and tab.

To temporarily allow pasting tabs in bash, run:

```
bind '"\t":self-insert'
```

To re-enable tab completion, run:

```
bind '"\C-i":complete'
```

If you're pasting text to emacs, you can use a function like this instead of command-v:

```
(defun pbpaste ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
    (point)
    (if mark-active (mark) (point))
    "pbpaste" nil t))
```

Comment: An example of my use case is to paste sections of TSV files into a remote ssh session terminal, bypassing the tedious multi-hop scp process. So this answer does not actually address my use case.

Comment: @javadba: In that case you should probably explain your use case in more detail. What sequence of ssh sessions, shells, etc are you trying to pass a tab through? Where is it going on the other end: into a file, into a shell, into stdin of some process, etc?

Comment: @GordonDavisson  updated the question

Answer (score 1):

In both linux and OS/x there does not appear to be a means to paste tabs into a terminal.  If anyone (eventually) comes up with a solution please feel free to add the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a workaround (at least in Linux)

- `v=$(cat)`
- then paste your text
- then ctrl-D to close the 'cat' command
- and there you have your text with tabs in $v, which you can output with `echo "$v"`

Comment: Maybe this works on *nix but i'm on macos where it does not. Will upvote anyways as an interesting idea